# Trying to format a Eval() in control is failing during runtime c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have not worked outside of Razor engine for a while, but on this current project I need to make changes to a template. I am trying to format the string output in the designer client side, but it is failing. The current code is as follows:

```
   <table>
       <!-- Data Result -->
         <tr>          
           <!-- Here we are just padding the results to have a fixed length of (".")  n = s.PadRight((t-n)+n1) -->                                                              
           <td><%Eval("Text").ToString().PadRight((40 - Eval("Text").ToString().Length), Convert.ToChar("."));%></div>
           <td><%Eval("Total").ToString().PadRight((10 - Eval("Total").ToString().Length), Convert.ToChar(" ")); %></div>
           <td>(<%CalcPercent(Eval("Total").ToString());%>)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Do you know if I cannot format this way, and have to do it outside of the control, or maybe before the Eval handles it? Doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work.

Do I have to first assign the Eval() value to a variable, then handle the formatting?

This is the error I get:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: This table is inside a control i.e. any repeater control? If not you can't use it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your missing an equal sign, your `Eval` should be: `<%= Eval("Total") %>`. I'm not entirely sure, but I do know the normal practice would be:

```
<div class="..." style="...">
     <%= Eval("Total") %>
</div>
```

Your either applying your style:

- Inline
- Id
- Class

I don't believe you can append in that manner, because it isn't an actual Control.  I would suggest the above though.

Comment: So are you saying I cannot format the Eval as so, and should do it another way? Like client side jQuery or code behind? And yes, I did forget the =.  lol  Thanks

Comment: Also, the problem I am having is trying to do the padding. When that is not there, it works fine.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't apply style elements to an eval, you can only apply them to particular controls that support it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get it working, so I went with the following solution. Kind of an awnser and kind of not.

```
 public static string GetFormattedStringPadRight(this string val, int length, char charToPad)
    {
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            returnValue = val.ToString().PadRight((40 - val.Length), charToPad);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

and then in the client side:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
          <!-- Data Result -->
            <tr>          
               <!-- Here we are just padding the results to have a fixed length of (".")  n = s.PadRight((t-n)+n1) -->                                                              
                 <td><%#Eval("Text").ToString().GetFormattedStringPadRight(40, Convert.ToChar(".")) %></div>
                 <td><%#Eval("Total").ToString().GetFormattedStringPadRight(10, Convert.ToChar(" ")) %></div>
                 <td>(<%#CalcPercent(Eval("Total").ToString())%>)</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I do not know why this formatting worked, but not my prior. Thanks.